# Change curreny position on dashboard Metric Chart

Tags: reporting, dashboard, currency, locale

On Dashboards, on Metric Chart, instead of correct settings of Locales for my country, **currency symbol is always shown before value**.

[image: Metric Chart]

It is incorrect for my country (Poland) as it should always be shown after the value like for the rest of the org: on reports, records, etc.

[image]

[image]

How I can set it up? Is this functionality not implemented from Salesforce yet?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right -- There is no way to change this setting in the dashboard chart yourself.

1. Open a Support request with Salesforce to describe the issue.
2. If they can't adjust it, then submit this as an issue on the IdeaExchange: https://issues.salesforce.com/#q=Zloty

Comment: Thank you a lot for a response :)